# Reescribir QUERY SQL en PANDAS DATAFRAME

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe

Tengo que traducir una operación de una consulta SQL en una serie de operaciones de pandas, el query es más complejo pero muestro un ejemplo minimo a partir del cuál puedo yo reproducir la complejidad del query.

Tengo una tabla de nombre `TABLE_1` con columnas `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E`,`F`,`G`,`PQR`,`DATE1`,`DATE2`,`DATE0`,`v1`,`v6`,`v7`,`v8` y se le aplica el siguiente query:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_1.[A], 
    TABLE_1.[B],  
    max(TABLE_1.[E]) AS [E],  
    TABLE_1.[DATE1], 
    TABLE_1.[DATE2], 
    sum(TABLE_1.v1) AS [NUEVO_NOMBRE_TABLA], 
    max(TABLE_1.[PQR]) AS [PQR],  
    sum(TABLE_1.v6) AS [EJEM_NOMBRE],                    
    (sum(TABLE_1.v6)+sum(TABLE_1.G))*0.03 AS NUEVO_NOMBRE_TABLA_2, 
    sum(TABLE_1.G) as G
FROM 
   TABLE_1
GROUP BY
    TABLE_1.[DATE0],
    TABLE_1.[A],
    TABLE_1.[B],
    TABLE_1.[DATE1],
    TABLE_1.[DATE2]
```

Mis conocimientos de python me permiten obtener la mayoría de las columnas, salvo los mútiples `sum` y `max`,
tengo entendido que `groupby([columnas_agrupacion])["v1"].sum()` da una parte del resultado deseado, pero también necesito los `max` y los otros `groupby`, así como la operación de suma   `sum(TABLE_1.v7)+sum(TABLE_1.v8)` que contiene la operación `sum` por agregación, la cuál no tengo idea de cómo hacer.

El query real tiene varias de estas operaciones mezcladas y más columnas, pero con un ejemplo de como aplicar operaciones de pandas para recrear el query sql me servirá como base para estructurar la consulta compleja que necesito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de investigar por mi cuenta, di con una solución increíble basada en unicamente `pandas`.

Si el equivalente de `TABLE` es `df`, entonces :

```
z=df.groupby(
    ["DATE0","A","B","DATE1","DATE2"],
    as_index = False
    ).agg(
        E = pd.NamedAgg(
            column = "E",
            aggfunc = max),
        NUEVO_NOMBRE_TABLA = pd.NamedAgg(
            column = "v1",
            aggfunc = sum),
        PQR = pd.NamedAgg(
            column = "PQR",
            aggfunc = max),
        EJEM_NOMBRE = pd.NamedAgg(
            column = "v6",
            aggfunc = sum),
        G = pd.NamedAgg(
            column = "G",
            aggfunc = sum)

z["NUEVO_NOMBRE_TABLA_2"] =  z.EJEM_NOMBRE + 0.03*z.G
```